# Why doesn't `array.include` [sic] show the correct output

Tags: ruby

I have:

```
num = ["jack","sparrow","terminator","leonidus"]
name = "jack"
```

The solution is:

```
if num.include? name
  puts " Jack is here"
else
  puts " Invite jack"
end
# => "Jack is here"
```

My old script is:

```
val = num.include? name
if val == "true"
  puts " Jack is here"
else
  puts " Invite jack"
end
# => "Invite jack"
```

Why is my old script not working? What is wrong with it?

Comment: It's because you are trying to check boolean value as `String`. Try changing that `val=="true"` just `val`

Comment: You're representing `true` as `"true"`. The second is a string.

Comment: Solution to what? In what sense is your script not working? What is wrong with it?

Comment: Also, cannot be reproduced.

Comment: Your title does not match the text. What is `array.include`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `include` method returns a boolean value. So your solution eliminates one of the steps, which is great. The old script didn't work because you were trying to compare a boolean value to a string. You could take away your quotes on `true` and you would have come up with a working solution: `if val == true`. Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, and since it's a check for boolean value, using just `val` would be enough here :)

Comment: @sawa It is a method that is used on an array that asks the array if it includes the argument that is passed in.

For example:
`[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].include?(2)    # true`
`[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].include?(10)  # false`

Comment: There is no such method. Also, your explanation and the example in the comment do not match.

Comment: Your explanation is "Easy" and to the point, thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

```
true == "true"
# => false
```

`true` is not equal to `"true"` even though `"true"` is a truthy value, that is, casted to boolean it will result true (`nil` is falsy, surprisingly `0` is truthy). To cast something to its boolean value, you can use this syntax: `!!variable`. You don't need to do that inside the `if` condition because it's already done internally.