# Array.include? myVariable not working as expected

Tags: arrays, ruby

I am coding a Ruby 1.9 script and I'm running into some issues using the `.include?` method with an array.

This is my whole code block:

```
planTypes = ['C','R','S'];
invalidPlan = true;
myPlan = '';


while invalidPlan  do
    print "Enter the plan type (C-Commercial, R-Residential, S-Student): ";
    myPlan = gets().upcase;
    if planTypes.include? myPlan
        invalidPlan = false;
    end
end
```

For troubleshooting purposes I added print statements:

```
while invalidPlan  do
    print "Enter the plan type (C-Commercial, R-Residential, S-Student): ";
    myPlan = gets().upcase;
    puts myPlan;                        # What is my input value? S
    puts planTypes.include? myPlan      # What is the boolean return? False
    puts planTypes.include? "S"         # What happens when hard coded? True
    if planTypes.include? myPlan
        puts "My plan is found!";       # Do I make it inside the if clause? Nope
        invalidPlan = false;
    end
end
```

Since I was getting the correct result with a hard-coded string, I tried `"#{myPlan}"` and `myPlan.to_s`.  However I still get a `false` result.

I'm new to Ruby scripting, so I'm guessing I'm missing something obvious, but after reviewing similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986386/check-if-a-value-exists-in-an-array-in-ruby) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33876916/why-doesnt-array-include-sic-show-the-correct-output), as well as checking the [Ruby Doc](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-include-3F), I'm at a loss as to way it's not acting correctly.

Comment: Is the down vote due to missing the `\n` character?  Would love some feed back when given down vote.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result of `gets` includes a newline (`\n`), which you can see if you print `myPlan.inspect`:

```
Enter the plan type (C-Commercial, R-Residential, S-Student): C
"C\n"
```

Add [`strip`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-strip) to clean out the unwanted whitespace:

```
myPlan = gets().upcase.strip;
```

```
Enter the plan type (C-Commercial, R-Residential, S-Student): C
"C"
```